# Is broadcasted packet received by its sender?

Tags: localhost, broadcast

Does the broadcast sender get data broadcasted by him?
I tested it on windows 7 and the answer seems to be YES, however is it standard behaviour?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is standard behavior. Normally, your OS just discards the packet because you don't have anything listening on that port.

You can test this by broadcasting to a port you are listening on. Here is an example using Packet Sender ( http://packetsender.com/ ). Packet Sender allows sending and receiving packets. I told it to broadcast to the UDP port it is listening on (port 55005). You can see I received a copy of the sent packet.

[image]